# Re: user list script

Tags: awk

How can you make this script output results to a file?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Use awk to do the heavy lifting.
#For lines with UID>=1000 (field 3) grab the home directory (field 6)
usrInfo=$(awk -F: '{if ($3 >= 1000) print $6}' < /etc/passwd)

IFS=$'\n' #Use newline as delimiter for for-loop
for usrLine in $usrInfo
do
  #Do processing on each line
  echo $usrLine
done
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340705/287340

Comment: Have you tried googling? Redirecting to a file is a very fundamental shell function.

Answer (score 0):

`./path/to/my/script.bash > output.txt`

on a side note, unless you have some home directories with spaces in them (bad idea if so!), then there's no need to set the field separator to `$'\n'`

Come to think of it, there's not much point in the for loop at all (unless you're planning on adding to this script?). You can just run:

`awk -F: '{if ($3 >= 1000) print $6}' /etc/passwd > output.txt`